# Setting a background image in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am having some confusing behavior in wxpython.  I just loaded the newest version (3.0.0.0) into a RHEL 6.4 with Python 2.6.6.

Most things seem to work, but my previous code for running a gui with a background image fails.  All the buttons work, etc, but the background is just the default gray one.

I tried tracking down the problem by running this minimal example from Mike Driscoll's python website (http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/), and had the same problem with no background showing up other than the default gray one (I previously used his example on another machine with an older version of wxpython [2.8.12.1] with no problems):

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
        self.frame = parent

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        for num in range(4):
            label = "Button %s" % num 
            btn = wx.Button(self, label=label)
            sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        hSizer.Add(sizer, 0, wx.TOP, 100)
        hSizer.Add((1,1), 0, wx.ALL, 75) 
        self.SetSizer(hSizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def OnEraseBackground(self, evt):
        """
        Add a picture to the background
        """
        # yanked from ColourDB.py
        dc = evt.GetDC()

        if not dc:
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
            rect = self.GetUpdateRegion().GetBox()
            dc.SetClippingRect(rect)
        dc.Clear()
        bmp = wx.Bitmap("butterfly.jpg")
        dc.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0)


########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(600,450))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Center()

########################################################################
class Main(wx.App):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        dlg = MainFrame()
        dlg.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Now, when I run this, I don't get any errors, but I determined that the function onEraseBackground never seems to run.  I don't know what is going wrong here; did wxpython 3.0.0.0 stop allowing this kind of image background setting procedure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try commenting out the

```
self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
```

line. Some other people have experienced the same issue and this line was the culprit - it prevents the `EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND` event being triggered.

You can also try replacing this line with

```
self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_ERASE)
```

to ensure the erase events are triggered.

Comment: Yep.  IIRC the SetBackgroundStyle behavior change was something that was migrating a bit during the 2.9 series, and the last step of changing the meaning of CUSTOM was changed some time after 2.9.4.